# Fundamental equations in Philosophy and Logic

Tags: logic

For the natural sciences it is easy to indicate the most important fundamental equations. If I want to explain Philosophy and Logic to a physicist or a chemist, what are considered the most important equations that define the subject that I should introduce and try to explain?

Comment: There is the Fundamental Theorem of Philosophy of course since there is always a "Fundamental Theorem of...", but it only says that there is a non-countable infinity of "-isms" in philosophy ;-)

Comment: there are no equations underlying philosophy

Comment: "For the natural sciences it is easy to indicate the most important equations that underlie the discipline." I don't believe this is the case. Are the most important equations in physics from QM, relativity, or thermodynamics? What kind of equations are fundamental in the biological or social sciences?

Comment: Another fundamental principle of philosophy is that to every difficult question there is a simple answer... and it's wrong. ;-)

Comment: Equations depend on phenomenon (the way we perceive). For example, you can write an equation adding apples because you take a range of weights and sizes by granted in the definition of an apple (there are no apples the size of a car). But philosophy is beyond such assumptions, so, equations don't apply in philosophy. Same happens with logic: you can describe phenomenon using logic, but you can't describe logic using logic, that would be circular.

Comment: The *fundamental equation* of philosophy is, for better/worse, not known to me. *El rachum*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philosophy can be amorphous enough to be "about" questions more than axioms/theorems. There are seemingly plausible symbolisms that can end up yielding undesired (by some people) results, like the [converse Barcan formula](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possibilism-actualism/#PossNeceLogiTrut): this variously says that {there exists a possible *X*, so possibly there exists an *X*} or, for necessity, you can get {there exists a necessary *X*, so necessarily there exists an *X*}.

But there are some results that are strongly accepted by, I think, most of the people who are aware of the relevant mathematical questions, and who are interested in answering them. Maybe more disagreement would manifest eventually, but "for now," a possible counterexample to "not even weak consensus" in philosophy: [a "general axiom" of normal modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#GenAxi). It's perhaps an obscure-seeming matter, but anyway, another arguable example comes from [second-order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#HighOrdeLogiVisVisTypeTheo): there are logical structures that are in some sense reducible to structures in a different-order logic. And this doesn't seem controversial, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what is currently called philosophy has very little to do with learning how to do much formal logic, and everything to do with learning what historical people who *also* didn't know how to do much formal logic had to say about things. Most of those people died before most of this stuff was discovered, so it's hardly their fault - but it is what it is. Learning how to work with those historical ideas has value, but learning formal logic is something else - *mathematics*.

The core laws of formal logic are identity: **A equals A**; non-contradiction: **A does not equal not-A**; and the excluded middle: **either B equals A or B does not equal A**.

From there you'll want to build up through binary logic, with which almost every physicist and many chemists will be intimately familiar from writing computer code and/or circuit design. Wikipedia has a [comprehensive guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to the binary logical operators, but learning to use them properly will take a lot of repetitions on practice problems.

The language of logic is mathematics, and the chances are that the physicist and chemist are pretty good at it. All scientists and philosophers *should* share a grounding in statistics, which you can't do properly without at least basic calculus.

Philosophy makes outsized use use of [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), which would probably be intimately familiar to a biologist, but may be new to or forgotten by a physicist or chemist. Bayes' theorem doesn't require any math beyond basic algebra in and of itself.

To go farther in formal logic (even for application to real-world problems) one will want a basic foundation in [abstract mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(mathematics)), by which point you'd probably be ready to start a masters degree program in mathematics, but may never have read a word of philosophy so labeled.